How is torsion on a subset of the circle defined modulo an irrational rotation?
Can you help me define torsion generated by modulo an irrational rotation?
Rational torsion
In a Prufer p-group the elements of $\Bbb Z[\frac1p]/\Bbb Z$ are arrived at by reducing $\Bbb Z[\frac1p]$ with addition modulo $1$.  This reduction $\pmod1$ might be seen as topologically conjugate to the identity function on the unit circle.  And we could equally use a product of multiple primes to generate our original set, and reduce by some other rational quantity which would give us another, different torsion group.
For example the products of the dyadic and ternary rationals in the interval $[0,\frac13)$ with addition modulo $\frac13$ form a group.  One might think of the cosets whose elements are drawn from $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ as orbits of the function $x\mapsto x+\frac13$ which has a corresponding rational rotation on the unit circle of $\exp{2x\pi\cdot i}\mapsto \exp{2(x+\frac13)\pi\cdot i}$.
Irrational torsion
Let us start with the set $\Bbb Z[\frac16]^+$: the products of all positive dyadic and ternary rationals .  Please note this will not necessarily yield a group - possibly a monoid or magma but I've tagged "torsion-group" for the relevance of the torsion property.
Instead of the addition mod $1$ relation in the rational example above, I wish to take a quotient of the set $\Bbb Z[\frac16]^+$ by dividing out the primes $2$ and $3$, so each element could be represented by a 5-rough natural number, and by the same token any given number $x$ also represents $x\cdot 2^j3^k:j,k\in\Bbb Z$. Let $H=\Bbb Z[\frac16]^+/\sim$.
This of course poses some problems, the most immediate of which is that $2^j3^k$ is dense in $\Bbb Q$.
The second problem is that we need algebra which works on such elements.  That is easily rectified because I can define affine transformations on the set of the form $x\mapsto ax+b\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)}$ which then respect the rays of the quotient.  That is entirely perfect for my purposes.
I am left trying to rectify the first problem somehow (this is where I need some guidance) with the following map:
Let $f$ be the self-map $[1/2,1)\to[1/2,1)$, denoted $f$:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{4x}3 &\text{if}& 0\le x<\frac34 \\
\frac{2x}3& \text{if}&  \frac34\le x <1.\end{cases}$$
It can be shown that $f$ is topologically conjugate to the irrational transformation $x\mapsto x+(1-\log_2(3))$ on the unit interval, proving the orbits of $f$ are dense in the set.
I believe this function can help me in the definition of the quotient above and in the study of its algebra.  In particular, am I right in thinking that the above function $f$, when restricted to $[\frac12,1)$ lands the members of any given coset into precisely two orbits?  If so, for each $5$-rough natural number I should be able to pick a unique representative in the interval $[\frac12,1)$ on which algebra will be easy, no?  I'm sure this is the right direction but I'm just a bit lost now.
Question
Is there enough here for somebody who knows what they're doing to point me in the right direction, help me use $f$ to define the quotient or its algebra, or name it, or give me the terminology for what I'm doing, or point me to relevant material, or describe in what way(s) my request is unclear or ill-defined?
Motivation
$h(x)=x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)-1}$ almost certainly acts transitively on $H$.  It is that which I am trying to prove, which would be equivalent to the Collatz conjecture.
Note: I have tagged general topology due to the relevance of homeomorphisms on the circle and dynamical systems due to the relevance of irrational rotations.

I'm having troubly disentangling undefined terminology ("$5$-rough"?...) I'm also having trouble locating an actual mathematical question in this post; helping you form a definition of some vaguely described concept is not really what happens on this site.

@LeeMosher sorry $5-$ rough means not factorable by $2$ or $3$.

@LeeMosher re vagueness of the question. Any reference material would be useful.  I see possibly related topics such as https://www.anvith.com/Irrational_Rotational_Algebras.pdf and https://msp.org/pjm/1981/93-2/pjm-v93-n2-p12-s.pdf do you have any knowledge of those and whether they're relevant?

There are many unclear aspects of this question. I hope it is rewritten more clearly and carefully. Even the first sentence makes no sense: In the Prüfer p-group, we don't "reduce" anything; it is simply defined as (ℤ{1/p],+)/ℤ.

@DanAsimov What I meant by that was that the $/\Bbb Z$ part semantically encapsulates reduce modulo $1$. I've re-worded it for you.

Also, I cannot assign any sensible meaning to how reduction modulo 1 can conceivably be "conjugate to the identity function on the unit circle", since it is a map from one additive group to a quotient group.

@DanAsimov if you send $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ to the unit circle using $x\mapsto \exp{2x\pi\cdot i}$ you should see how this map to the unit circle has the exact effect I describe of reducing the set modulo $1$ creating exactly the Prufer $2-$ group out of it.  The reduction $(\pmod1)$ on the real line is conjugate to the identity map on the unit circle. Is that clear now?

Everything in your comment was already crystal clear until the last sentence, which I cannot understand. Maybe we have different meanings that we assign to the word "conjugate". For me two morphisms f, g : X → X of an object to itself are conjugate exactly when there exists an automorphism h : X → X such that hf = gh (here adjacency means composition of morphisms).

That's right @DanAsimov same definition. You will see by the morphism in my comment that $x, x+1, x+2, x+3,...$ all conjugate to the same place on the circle, i.e. related by the identity function. This is basic group theory that modular addition on the real line conjugates to periodic points on the circle. In the case of the Prufer groups, mod $1$ conjugates to identity or exactly one rotation of the circle.

I'm glad we agree on the definition. To me that means that the sentence "This reduction (mod 1) might be seen as topologically conjugate to the identity function on the unit circle" does not mean anything. This is because reduction mod 1 is not a morphism from a space to itself.

@DanAsimov there's a slight discrepancy between the map from the unit interval to the circle, and the entire real line to the circle. When you do the latter, you make a projection which reduces the domain mod $1$ in the sense it does not inject whereas the former does.

@DanAsimov sorry I have another perspective which might be clearer to you. Reduction mod $1$ is the identity function on the unit interval and therefore it is a morphism from a space to itself. I also wonder if you think I am claiming reduction mod $1$ is the conjugating function, which I am not.

Mathematical definitions do not mean "almost" or "kind of". Nor do they depend on one's perspective. They either apply or they do not. This appears to be an understanding that is missing from your posts.
